# Escaping & in a URL

Tags: java, jsp, url, uri

I am using jsps and in my url I have a value for a variable like say "L & T". Now when I try to retrieve the value for it by using `request.getParameter` I get only "L". It recognizes "&" as a separator and thus it is not getting considered as a whole string.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode("L & T", "utf8")
```

this outputs the URL-encoded, which is fine as a GET parameter:

```
L+%26+T
```

Answer (score 1):

A literal ampersand in a URL should be encoded as: `%26`

```
// Your URL
http://www.example.com?a=l&t

// Encoded
http://www.example.com?a=l%26t
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "URL encode" the parameters to avoid this problem. The format of the URL query string is:
`...?<name>=<value>&<name>=<value>&<etc>`
All `<name>`s and `<value>`s need to be URL encoded, which basically means transforming all the characters that could be interpreted wrongly (like the &) into %-escaped values. See this page for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

If you're *generating* the problem URL with Java, you use this method:
`String str = URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8");`

Generating the URL elsewhere (some templates or JS or raw markup), you need to fix the problem at the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UriUtils#encode(String source, String encoding)` from *Spring Web*. This utility class also provides means for encoding only some parts of the URL, like `UriUtils#encodePath`.