# Escaping ampersands in URLs for HttpClient requests

Tags: java, http, url, escaping, apache-commons-httpclient

So I've got some Java code that uses Jakarta HttpClient like this:

```
URI aURI = new URI( "http://host/index.php?title=" + title + "&action=edit" );
GetMethod aRequest = new GetMethod( aURI.getEscapedPathQuery());
```

The problem is that if `title` includes any ampersands (&), they're considered parameter delimiters and the request goes screwy...  and if I replace them with the URL-escaped equivalent `%26`, then this gets double-escaped by getEscapedPathQuery() into `%2526`.

I'm currently working around this by basically repairing the damage afterward:

```
URI aURI = new URI( "http://host/index.php?title=" + title.replace("&", "%26") + "&action=edit" );
GetMethod aRequest = new GetMethod( aURI.getEscapedPathQuery().replace("%2526", "%26"));
```

But there *has* to be a nicer way to do this, right?  Note that the title can contain any number of unpredictable UTF-8 chars etc, so escaping everything else is a requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping & in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197993/escaping-in-a-url)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
...
...
URI aURI = new URI( "http://host/index.php?title=" + URLEncoder.encode(title,"UTF-8") + "&action=edit" );
GetMethod aRequest = new GetMethod( aURI.getPathQuery());
```

Check [java.net.URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) for more info.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to work, I'm still getting the double-encoded %2526?  All URLEncoder does is replace the & with a %26, which is the same as my original replace operation.

Comment: OK I fixed my answer. You shouldn't use .getEscapedPathQuery() because the title is now escaped by URLEncoder.

Comment: Sorry, my brain was mush when I wrote my first reply -- you're right, it's enough to encode just parameter and leave the rest untouched.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling getEscapedPathQuery() if you don't want the escaping? Just decide who's responsibility it is and be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class.

> Utility class for HTML form encoding. This class contains static
>   methods for converting a String to the
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format. For more information
>   about HTML form encoding, consult the HTML specification.

Comment: Readers should be aware that encoding to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not exactly the same as URI encoding. Many of the escapes are the same, but not all of them.