# How to replace specific '&' within a URL string for parsing

Tags: java, parsing, url, ampersand

The URL string can be very dynamic.
It can have any number and combination of parameters.
For example :

```
  myHost?parm1=Data1&parm2=Data2&parm3=Data3
```

Most parsing routines can be implemented just fine in this scenario, but what if the data itself contains a '&'.
For example :

```
  myHost?parm1=Data1&1b&parm2=Data2&2b&parm3=Data3&3b
```

Using the StringTokenizer or URLEncoder is an all or nothing process. 
Since the parameter names can vary, they can't be used as part of the search. 
The names value pairs need to be broken down with the data containing the '&' needs to be kept as such :

```
parm1=Data1&1b
parm2=Data2&2b
parm3=Data3&3b
```

Any Java recommendation on an implementation to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

`&` in query string values should be *percent-encoded*, as `%26`. In your example, they should look like:

```
parm1=Data1%261b
parm2=Data2%262b
parm3=Data3%263b
```

So it should be easy to split a properly encoded URL, simply by the `&`.

When creating the URL, the client program must URL-encode each parameter value. Then format a URL by joining key and (encoded-)value by `=`, and the list of key-value pairs by `&`. If the client program doesn't URL-encode the parameter values, then the server program won't have a way to distinguish the embedded `&` from the value separator `&`.

Comment: Does this mean it is expected that the user enter %26 themselves when the data contains a '&' but then use '&' in other places of the URL?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the client program to encode the `&` properly

Comment: All that I have seen essentially does an all or nothing type of encoding and when that is done you still can't differentiate between the '&' within the data and the '& which separates the data.

Comment: When creating the URL, the client program must URL-encode each parameter value. Then format a URL by joining key and (encoded-)value by `=`, and the list of key-value pairs by `&`. If the client program doesn't URL-encode the parameter values, then the server program won't have a way to distinguish the embedded `&` from the value separator `&`.

Comment: There could be 1,000 different parameters. Based on the reply are you indicating that the client application track all 1,000+ parameters, extract the name value pair then encode?

Comment: No. I'm talking about the client application that has the name-value pairs in some sort of dictionary or form as input. The input at the source. The program logic that converts the name-value pairs to a flat string, that's the point in time when the values should be URL-encoded, before putting them in a flat string. It's at the time of this conversion when the URL-encoding should be applied.

Comment: If I am following, essentially the client application should know what are the available parameters that can be used. If so, that is definitely not currently set up. Currently the client application simply passes the URL along. Since there could be a 1,000 or so different parameters how are these usually stored? In a file, in a database or properties file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility in Java which encodes urls for you (java.net.URLEncoder), and it should take care of replacing the ampersand.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558111/escaping-ampersands-in-urls-for-httpclient-requests) is a similar post to yours.

Also, you can read up on some [articles](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) that give some advice on url encoding.

Comment: I saw that example and unless I missed something that will process all the '&' symbols and not just the ones associated with the data.