# EditText removing ampersand and rest of text

Tags: android, post, android-edittext, ampersand

In my EditText I'll have a message such as `Punch & Judy are is an amazing show` but when I get it to come to displaying it it is just coming up with `Punch` any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm sending it to a server with using a POST request. But when I get the response It just doesn't have it.

Comment: What's the way you interact with the `EditText`?

Comment: Depending on how you're setting the EditText, you may need to use `\&` or `&amp;`

Comment: I'm sending it to a server with using a POST request. But when I get the response It just doesn't have it. With `\&` and `&amp;` @MichaelDodd

Comment: Ah, sending via POST, that's a very important bit of information. Please include it in your original question. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending it via a POST request, you can safely encode using `java.net.URLEncoder.encode` e.g.

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Punch & Judy are is an amazing show", "utf8")
```

See also - [Escaping & in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197993/escaping-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

As & is not allowed so in place of this you can use `&amp;` instead

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `res/string.xml` file as:

```
<string name="give_your_name">Punch &amp; Judy are is an amazing show</string>
```

Use in `EditText` as:

```
<EditText
  .....
  android:text="@string/give_your_name"           
 />
```

Keep in mind:

```
Entity                     Character    Name    Usage
left angle bracket            <          lt     &lt;
right angle bracket           >          gt     &gt;
ampersand                     &          amp    &amp;
single quote or apostrophe    '          apos   &apos;
double quote or speech mark   "          quot   &quot;
```